# groupMembershipClaims - getting membership information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to make AAD to provide group information. I have changed manifest file of my Web App:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

I would expect my Identity to contain membership information, but it dosent. I have tried following:

```
ClaimsIdentity claimsId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var rr = claimsId2.FindFirst("groups");
var rr2 = claimsId2.Claims.ToList();
```

But both are empty. Do you need to do more than changing the manifest file?

Comment: Have you signed out and signed in again?

Comment: Nopes, after doing that I got all of my claims. Please post an answer and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we figured out in the comments, it required a sign out and sign in to refresh the claims from Azure AD.